# Carbocation stability order 3

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

I have come to an example which suggests that +M effect of -OH is better than =O . How is that possible?
Here is the picture with their Hydride affinities (in Kcal/mol)
[image]

I think -OH should have stronger +M , as it's lone pair's hybridization is sp2 which will be closer in energy of sp2 orbital of carbon  centre as compare to sp hybridization of =O .

Source: www.cpp.edu/~psbeauchamp/pdf/315_SN_E_answers.pdf

Problem no. 21 , page no. 10 .

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open, but to prevent it from getting closed as homework, you should edit your post and include your thoughts and why the source sounds weird.

Comment: Ok I've added my thoughts too and this is from  California State Polytechnic University-Pomona

.